# How do I properly pass form.errors after an invalid form submission

Tags: python, django

I have created a registration view where I want `ValidationError`(s) to be displayed after a form is submitted but it happens to be *invalid* `form.is_valid() == False`. `ChefRegisterationForm` is a subclass of `UserCreationForm`. If the form is valid, a flash message will do. With what I have, it gets the job done, but there has to be a cleaner way than having two `render` statements in the view. How could this be refactored so that there is only one `render` statement?

```
def register_chef(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user_form = ChefRegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if new_user_form.is_valid():
            user = new_user_form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(
                request,
                f"Logged in: {user}!"
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("menu:menu_list"))
        return render(request, 'chef/register_chef.html', {'form': new_user_form})
    new_user_form = ChefRegisterationForm()
    return render(request, 'chef/register_chef.html', {'form': new_user_form})
```

```
{% extends 'index.html '%}

{% block content %}
    {% if form.errors %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p>{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <form action="{% url 'chef:register' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {{ field }}
        {% endfor %}
        <button>Register</button>
    </form>
    {% for key in form.errors %}
        {{ key }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I'm missing something, but how about this?

```
def register_chef(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_user_form = ChefRegisterationForm(request.POST)
        if new_user_form.is_valid():
            user = new_user_form.save()
            login(request, user)
            messages.info(request, f"Logged in: {user}!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("menu:menu_list"))
    else:
        new_user_form = ChefRegisterationForm()
    return render(request, 'chef/register_chef.html', {'form': new_user_form})
```

You might want to take a look at the [class-based `FormView`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) which -I think- would reduce the boilerplate you have to write:

```
class ChefRegisterView(FormView):
    form_class = ChefRegisterationForm
    success_url = reverse("menu:menu_list")
    template_name = 'chef/register_chef.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = new_user_form.save()
        login(request, user)
        messages.info(request, f"Logged in: {user}!")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```